# Como emitir outliers com ggplot + geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho o `gráfico`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset<-as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(6*1000,1500,200),ncol=6))
cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])

dataset%>%
  gather(.,key='group',value='var',V1:V6)%>%
  ggplot(aes(group,var,fill=kmeans))+
  facet_grid(kmeans~.)+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color='yellow',outlier.shape=21,
                 outlier.fill='black',outlier.size=1)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")+
  theme_dark()
```

[image: Gráfico:]

Tenho duas perguntas:

- existe alguma função dentro de `geom_boxplot` capaz de emitir os *outliers* em valores?
- existe alguma forma de emitir apenas a primeira ocorrência de *outlier*, em valor, para cima e para baixo da caixa? Suponha que os *outliers* sejam: 1,4 e 5 abaixo e 500, 501, 502 acima. Assim, gostaria de emitir apenas 5 e 500.

Comment: Pq você quer omitir apenas a 1ª ocorrência de outlier seja para cima ou baixo da caixa?

Comment: Para filtrar a partir destes valores.

Comment: Existe algum motivo para ser no `ggplot2`?

Comment: Para permanecer no framework `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de mais nada vou recriar os dados com uma `seed` para que os resultados possamos ser reproduzidos.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
dataset <- as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(6*1000,1500,200),ncol=6))
cluster <- kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans <- as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])
```

e nomear o gráfico para que possamos usá-lo adiante.

```
p <- dataset%>%
  gather(.,key='group',value='var',V1:V6) >%
ggplot(aes(group,var,fill=kmeans))+
  facet_grid(kmeans~.)+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color='yellow',outlier.shape=21,
               outlier.fill='black',outlier.size=1)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")+
  theme_dark()
```

### Obtendo *ouliers* no `ggplot2`

No [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) os outliers são calculados no momento em que o gráfico vai ser desenhado (quando der `print(plot)`).

A função responsável por isso será a função `StatBoxplot` ([código-fonte](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-boxplot.r)) que é executada dentro do "ambiente" do gráfico.

É possível forçar a execução dos cálculos por meio da função `ggplot_build()`. Assim temos

```
calculado <- ggplot_build(p)
```

O objeto criado tem uma elemento chamado `data` que possui três `data.frames`. O primeiro deles se refere aos dados usados para a construção do **boxplot**. Neste `data.frame` há uma lista com os *outliers* de cada boxplot chamada "outliers".

```
outliers <- calculado$data[[1]]$outliers
str(outliers)
List of 18
 $ : num 2148
 $ : num [1:4] 2059 2066 1191 2158
 $ : num [1:5] 992 1914 930 973 1819
 $ : num [1:3] 910 932 874
 $ : num [1:7] 2094 1163 2154 2085 2189 ...
 $ : num [1:3] 966 2072 2117
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num [1:2] 961 890
 $ : num [1:5] 1036 998 1940 2047 988
 $ : num [1:2] 916 2079
 $ : num [1:6] 949 2000 922 1946 1909 ...
 $ : num [1:6] 1065 2038 2050 1031 1085 ...
 $ : num [1:2] 968 2015
 $ : num [1:3] 2137 2178 2063
 $ : num [1:4] 2104 1262 1259 2184
 $ : num [1:3] 1003 1975 1931
 $ : num 891
 $ : num [1:3] 862 848 1962
```

## Obtendo os enésimos *outliers*

```
primeiros <- function(outliers, lower, upper) {
  primeiro_baixo <- max(outliers[outliers < lower])
  primeiro_cima <- min(outliers[outliers > upper])

  c(primeiro_baixo, primeiro_cima) %>% 
    map_dbl(~ ifelse(is.infinite(.x), NA, .x))
}

dados <- calculado$data[[1]]
pmap(list(dados$outliers, dados$lower, dados$upper), primeiros)
```

## Usando o pacote `graphics`

O pacote `graphics` já vem no `R` (é o pacote que possui a função `plot`, por exemplo) e tem uma função que pode facilitar essa tarefa.

```
res <- boxplot(var ~ group, gather(dataset, key = 'group', value = 'var', V1:V6))
res$out
# [1] 2148.2080  971.3702  967.8154  938.0451  979.6601 2038.3428 2036.9718 ...
```

Comment: Olá, Tomás. Creio que a parte `retiramos` dasd` esteja desconexa com o restante do texto.

Comment: Já resolvi. Obrigado